# What are staleTime and cacheTime in React-Query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have read React Query docs. Still, I do not understand how to use staleTime & cacheTime for data caching.

I want to store data for 2 mins in the cache after first-time API call. No matter if the component mounts or unmounts, I don't want an API call for 2 mins after the first time I got the data.

I used this but it does not call API after 2 min if I use **staletime** only & it calls API every time (on-mount component & unmount component) if I use **cachetime** only.

So, what is the problem? And what is the best way to do this?

```js
const query = useQuery(
  ["getUserList"], 
  getUserList, 
  {
    staleTime: 120000,
    cacheTime: 120000,
  }
);
```

Comment: `cacheTime` was renamed as `gcTime` in v5 [for less confusion](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/vue/guides/migrating-to-v5#rename-cachetime-to-gctime).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> No matter component mounts or unmounts, I don't want an API call for 2 mins after the first time get data

That is what `staleTime` is doing. `staleTime` tells you how fresh you data is. It is very similar to `Cache-Control: max-age=120`.

So if you set `staleTime: 120000`, in your example, you're guaranteed to *not* get another network request for two minutes after the first successful one.

---

`cacheTime` is something totally different. Think about it as a garbage-collect time. It basically describes how long data should be kept in the cache before it can be garbage collected. This is only relevant for unused queries, because active queries can per definition not be garbage collected.

I have also outlined this differences in [my blog](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/practical-react-query#the-defaults-explained):

> StaleTime: The duration until a query transitions from fresh to stale. As long as the query is fresh, data will always be read from the cache only - no network request will happen! If the query is stale (which per default is: instantly), you will still get data from the cache, but a background refetch can happen under certain conditions.

> CacheTime: The duration until inactive queries will be removed from the cache. This defaults to 5 minutes. Queries transition to the inactive state as soon as there are no observers registered, so when all components which use that query have unmounted.

---

> I used this but it does not call API after 2 min

This is something totally different. When `staleTime` elapses, your data is marked as stale - but that doesn't mean it will be instantly refetched. `staleTime` defaults to `zero` so that wouldn't work at all.

If you want to fetch every 2 minutes, set a `refetchInterval`:

`refetchInterval: 120000`

Comment: Thanks a lot. but how can I achieve something like I want No API call for 2 min after the first success request & after if component mount or unmount & 2min already done then there should be API call?

Comment: That is what staleTime is doing :) You can easily try that out in our codesandbox examples.

Answer (score 17):

I've recently shared an article about React Query cacheTime vs staleTime: https://medium.com/doctolib/react-query-cachetime-vs-staletime-ec74defc483e

In short, here's one mind model to help you understand: queries are made in two steps.

#### Step 1: respond as fast as possible ⚡️

First, React Query will try to serve a response as fast as possible. For that, it'll look for a cached value. If it doesn't find a valid (non-expired) cache, then it will trigger a call to the back-end.

#### Step 2: think about what we've just done

Now that React Query has already served a first value, it can take the time to think about stale time. So the question is now: is this data still fresh (not stale)? If yes, then it means that the previously served data is not considered fresh anymore, so we'll have to trigger a second request to the back-end.

The first step is cacheTime; the second one, staleTime. Voilà.

Here's a small (non-UML-compliant) chart that I've made for myself:

[image]

Hope this over-simplification of reality makes it clearer for you!